# publish ports on specific network interface in docker container

Tags: docker

Let's say I've got a container with 2 networks: net1, net2 and I'd like to publish port 80 that's on net2. How can I do that?

What I've observed is that docker binds ports on the interface which network's name is alphabetically first (here it will be net1)

Relevant code:

```
# docker-compose.yml

services:
  app:
    networks:
      net1:
        aliases: app_on_net1
      net2:
        aliases: app_on_net2
    publish:
      - 8080:80
```

//

```
#nginx.conf

server {
  listen app_on_net2:80;
}
```

EDIT:

You can find more info about the problem in the repository containing problem example at https://github.com/marzelin/example-so-54632371

Comment: I don't think that's the case, docker exposes a port on all networks

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more in what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Siyu i use docker on windows (not sure if that's relevant) and if configure nginx server to listen on net2 interface I'm not able to access the server on the published port. If I listen on net1 everything works fine.

Comment: @Sebastian I want to disable access to the published ports in another network (net1) by configuring server to listen on net2 interface. But if I listen on net2, the ports are not accessible from the host even though they are specified in docker-compose port section.

Comment: @marzelin do you have a working example? I'm having a hard time to understand your needs.

Comment: @Sebastian I've created repo with example configuration https://github.com/marzelin/example-so-54632371

Comment: @marzelin I think it has to do with the fact the nginx is not being exposed in `eth0`, instead, you are binding port 80 to eth1. By default, and not ~possible~ easy way to change, the default route is via eth0, so you won't be able to connect from the host.